# Behavior of collimated beam inside tubular first-surface-mirror

Tags: optics, reflection, laser, laser-interaction

Picture a cylindrical tube, the interior surface of which is a 1st-surface mirror coating.  Visualize the diameter of this tube as circumscribing an equilateral triangle with sides A,B,C.  The plane defined by the triangle is thus perpendicular to the long axis ('X') of the cylinder.  Now, via a hole made in the side of the tube at one of the vertices (say 'a,b'), introduce a beam of collimated light (e.g. laser diode source).  Say the 3 vertices of this imaginary triangle are all at a point 'P' along the 'X' axis; the beam is directed on a path drawn from 'a,b':X=p,
to a point 'a,c':X=p+n.  In other words, at a slight angle off of the perpendicular line 'A'.  (Hope you can visualize that! I don't know how to draw pictures in this context!).  The question is this: will the concave nature of the tube compensate at all for the elongation that the slight off-axis angle of incidence imposes at the first reflection point? How does this deformation influence the collimated nature of the beam (if at all)?  Can I expect the beam to bounce around the tube until it emerges at the other end?  And how can I estimate or calculate what its shape would be?
  Hope this makes some kind of sense!  I'm not a physicist, so any help with this is appreciated!

Comment: A picture would be very helpful. It is not too difficult to insert a figure into your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have done essentially this by sending a laser beam down a long, narrow, cylindrical vacuum tube. The goal was to get the beam through the tube without hitting the sides at all. But before it was aligned, the beam bounced around between the walls, ultimately emerging dramatically distorted.

I can tell you:

1. The light will make it out the end unless you introduce lossy reflections or an absorptive medium filling the cylinder.
2. The state of the beam is highly unpredictable and virtually impossible to calculate by hand except for in a couple of extremely symmetric situations (or in the limit where the cylinder radius is large compared to the beam radius and cylinder length, which sort of defeats the purpose of the question).

You would need to simulate your system numerically.

The curvature of the walls will focus the beam (in one dimension only). But the beam is propagating off-axis, and in general the focus is off-axis as well. Moreover, there will be spherical aberration of the focus, which could become very significant depending on the situation. Every reflection will distort the beam according to its precise angle of incidence and divergence at the point of reflection. This is a very complex 3D problem; good luck!

Comment: due to the focusing behavior at each reflection point, I can't help but wonder if there might be an inherent compensating "correction" along the way?  I'm thinking that if the ratio of cylinder radius to beam radius is very large, the nth reflection point result might just be "useful" (in my application).  You are right, BTW... this is more complex than I first thought! :)